# How to send a list of integers in the body of an http request to postman?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, web

I created a simple controller with a list of integers in the parameters. But when I tried to send a request from the postman, I got this response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-03-11T09:58:15.535+00:00",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "path": "/api/telegram/sendCustomMessage"
}
```

My Controller:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RequestMapping("/api/telegram")
public class TelegramBotController {
    private final TelegramService telegramService;

    @Autowired
    public TelegramBotController(TelegramService telegramService) {
        this.telegramService = telegramService;
    }


    @PostMapping("/sendCustomMessage")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> sendCustomMessage(
            @RequestBody List<Integer> accounts,
            String message
    ) {
//        telegramService.sendGroupMessageByAccountIdList(accountIds, message);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

}
```

My request body

```
{
    "accounts": [1, 2, 3],
    "message": "Custom Message"
}
```

I think I make mistakes in the body

Answer (score 2):

Your endpoint signature is not correct, instead of using:

```
... sendCustomMessage(@RequestBody List<Integer> accounts, String message) ...
```

you can create a custom object that holds both attributes, for example:

```
class CustomBody {
  private List<Integer> accounts;
  private String message;
  // Getter, Setter
}
```

and then:

```
public ResponseEntity<Void> sendCustomMessage(@RequestBody CustomBody body)
```

Comment: I created an entry for a custom body and changed the controller, but I still get the same error 
Controller
    @PostMapping("/sendCustomMessage")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> sendCustomMessage(
            @RequestBody CustomMessageDTO customMessageDTO
            ) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
Record
public record CustomMessageDTO(
        List<Integer> accounts,
        String message
) {
}
Body
{
    "accounts": [1,2,3],
    "message": "Custom Message"
}

Comment: @Danil I just try it and it works very well with me

Comment: @Danil it's because you use record. record only support for newer version spring boot and newer jackson as request body. if you still use spring boot 2.x or older jackson, use class instead as request body.